# How can I print specific column from the file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a specific column from a file. Here is my code:

```
rdf_f = open("substrate.txt")
for line in rdf_f:
    (x, y, z) = line.split()
    m = list(y)
rdf_f.close()
print(m)
```

I simply need to print the column in the y coordinate. But I can only print one value.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that:

```
m=list(y)
```

creates a new list every time. Try:

```
rdf_f = open("substrate.txt")
for line in rdf_f:
    (x, y, z) = line.split()
    print(y)
rdf_f.close()
```

or if you want to print after closing the file and/or to create a list of y coordinates:

```
rdf_f = open("substrate.txt")
m = []
for line in rdf_f:
    (x, y, z) = line.split()
    m.append(y)
rdf_f.close()
print(m)
```

you can also use with so you don't have to close the file manually.